# Yii Cgridview update function not working

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I've been working for this for a very long time and I'm nowhere near to understanding what I'm doing so wrong (yii beginner so please show some patience with me).

I have this code in my view code

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('symptomCategory',
                                         '',            // selected item from the $data
                                     $this->getSymptomCategories(), 
                                        array(
                                              'id'=>'categorySelectDropDown',
                                              'prompt'=>"Select Symptom Category",
                                              )); 





    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'symptoms-grid',
            'selectableRows'=>1, //ability to select one symptom at a time
            'dataProvider'=>$model2->search(),
            //'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'symptomsSelectGrid'),
            'columns'=>array(
                'symptomCode',
                'title',
                'inclusions',
                'exclusions',
                'symptomCategory',

            ),
    ));
```

And my js function is this:

```
$('#categorySelectDropDown').change(function()
        {
            var symptomCategory = $('#categorySelectDropDown').val();

            $('#symptoms-grid').yiiGridView('update', 
            {
                data: symptomCategory.serialize()
            });
            return false;
        });
```

I've tried with $(this).serialize() too. Anyway.

According to examples I've found online this should work, but nope, it doesn't update the cgridview. $this->getSymptomCategories() returns an array of array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B' ect. ect.)

BTW I am creating a model2 = new Symptoms; inside a view rendered by a controller of a different model because I want to use the choice from the gridview to fill in a form of the other model. Any help, documentation (haven't found any useful online), advice, ect will be really appreciated. Thank you for oyur time

Comment: I have found the problem. The gridview's ajax update url is towards the controller the renders it (in this case the sympomtshistorycontroller, since as I said I want to use the resulting grid view so the user can use it to pick a symptom for search), BUT the gridview is of the symptoms model. So what I do is I create a new sympptoms model ($model2 = new Symptoms;) inside the rendered partial view, which breaks MCV architecture....the problem is I have no idea how to fix it, cause I do need to render the gridview of symptoms inside a view belonging to another controller...hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way of updating yiiGridView

```
 $.fn.yiiGridView.update('symptoms-grid', { 
      data: $('#symptomCategory').serialize() // your form id
 });
```

There can be many reasons why yiiGridView seems like it is not updating, one of the them is that AJAX request is not being sent, another common reason is that search condition logic is not correct, or the requested action does not pass the post data to the model, resulting in the same data being returned, making it look like it is not updating.

See if the AJAX request going to the server from firebug/console etc. If it is going then check if the post data is correct and finally check  the model+controller logic is correct and the criteria of `CActiveDataProvider` is reflecting your search condition

Comment: Doesn't chagne anything :/

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to find a solution yet but you've helped me in understanding it a bit better. Anyway, there are no AJAX requests happening.

Comment: hope you solve it, it looks to me based on your comment it is  likely there is javascript error on your page not necessarily in the same part of the code, check for that

Comment: I am getting an error message (Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.
 
return !val || val.specified ? elem.value : elem.text; ) but from what I got on google it's an error of jquery and not my code. Even when I tried the various solutions I found online, nothing worked

Comment: I have found the problem. The gridview's ajax update url is towards the controller the renders it (in this case the sympomtshistorycontroller, since as I said I want to use the resulting grid view so the user can use it to pick a symptom for search), BUT the gridview is of the symptoms model. So what I do is I create a new sympptoms model ($model2 = new Symptoms;) inside the rendered partial view, which breaks MCV architecture....the problem is I have no idea how to fix it, cause I do need to render the gridview of symptoms inside a view belonging to another controller...hope someone can help.